# How can we reduce the width of bar using iReport

Tags: java, jasper-reports, ireport

I have a problem with `iReport`. When I tried with following query I didn't get wrong bar diagram. The sql query is as follows

```sql
SELECT 2 as num, client.name, count(user.client_id) as tot 
FROM users as user, clients as client 
WHERE user.client_id in($P{clientid1},$P{clientid2}) and registered = '1' 
and user.client_id=client.id group by user.client_id
```

When I pass two *`clientid`* numbers dynamically it shows only one bar with huge width. And my requirement is to show one bar for a one *`clientid`*.

plz anybody help....

Otherwise create 3d bar diagram with the above sql query

Comment: Check property option of "Print When Details Overflows" and then test.